# How to use JBoss logging brought by Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, jboss, jboss-logging

I am writing standalone java application which is using Hibernate. Maven brought `jboss-logging` library for me. I am not using JBoss. The question is: can I log with this library only, or I need to download some logging implementation like `log4j`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JBoss Logging is just a logging facade. To configure your loggers, e.g. use/add handlers, you need a log manager like JBoss Log Manager, the J.U.L. log manager, logback or log4j.

JBoss Logging will attempt to discover which log manager is being used. You can specify which log manager you'd like to use with the `org.jboss.logging.provider` system property. The allowed values for `org.jboss.logging.provider' are:

- jboss - for JBoss Log Manager
- jdk - For the J.U.L. log manager
- log4j - For the log4j log manager
- slf4j - For logback with slf4j

Hibernate uses JBoss Logging for it's i18n capabilities, it's vararg logging methods and the ability to not be tied to a log manager.

Of course you can absolutely use JBoss Logging in your project. If you want to configure logging handlers you'd also have to use a log manager as well.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, jboss-logging is more a extra layer on top of normal logging api, to provide more sophisticated feature like i18n etc.

JBoss-logging can use other logging library (e.g. SLF4J) as the underlying handler for log.

I believe if you are writing a simple standalone Java app, you do not need to use JBoss-logging (unless you know you really want and need to do so).

Using SLF4J (with LogBack or Log4J binding) will be a good choice.  Visit http://slf4j.org for more information

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `jboss-logging` and your logger implementation in your classpath and set the system property `org.jboss.logging.provider` to `log4j`, `jdk`, `slf4j` or `jboss` depending on what you want. In theory autodetection may also work.

https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logging/LoggerProviders.java#L29